# Swift video file captured doesn't exists in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

Captured a video in one viewcontroller and trying to preview it in another and upload it. Everything works fine till when I try the uploading where it gives me file doesn't exists

VideoRecorderViewController.swift

```
func finishRecording(outputFileURL: URL!) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in

                let path = outputFileURL.path
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                   //it comes here 

                }


                let vc: VideoViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoVC") as? VideoViewController
                if let validVC: VideoViewController = vc {
                    validVC.videoURL = outputFileURL as NSURL?
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(validVC, animated: true)

                }

            }
}
```

VideoViewController.swift

```
  var videoURL = NSURL(string: "")
     @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {

            print (self.videoURL!)

// returns file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/228FAD74-B7C3-4838-8114-ED16D995FF9A/tmp/3B256E17-9875-4610-B8B3-348FBFAEC409.mov

            print (self.videoURL!.path!)

          //returns /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/228FAD74-B7C3-4838-8114-ED16D995FF9A/tmp/3B256E17-9875-4610-B8B3-348FBFAEC409.mov

                let path = self.videoURL!.path!
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                   // "never comes"


                }

    }
```

Comment: Try to Convert It into NSData and pass its reference to another controller instead outputFileURL.

Comment: @DheerajD : for good practise, we should not pass NSData to another controller. it will create Memory retain problem in your code

Comment: Agree but the thing is we cannot  keep reference of video for long.

Comment: I faced the same issue some time before and resolved using what i suggest

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, yes this is the only solution worked, 24 hours of struggle came to an end.